# SQL Report initial toggle state

Tags: sql, settings, reportingservices-2005

I have a report that contains a table of data this data is set to be intially collapsed using the initial toggle state property setting, however this does not happen the (sub-data) for want of  abetter word still appears, and to make things even more confusing the icon that is placed at the side changes from the expected minus in expanded mode to a plus (which I would expect when the data is collapsed)

I have been trying to solve this for hours now but I cannot find a setting that will remedy the situation. I have tried selecting the row and **edit group** this allows me to set the rows to be exapnded by the relevant parent field, which I do set, but when applying the collapsed setting to the sub data, it is ignored.

Any help would be much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there seemed to be a strange error where if i edited the group directyly the group displayed the settings buit the page did nor solved by editing the page settings as well